# Complie Boost c++ library for iOS devices running on armv7s

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, boost

I've successfully built boost c++ 1_44_0 library for iPhone/iPad on armv6 and armv7 but i can't seem to create a build for the newer devices running on armv7s.

Used BoostOnIphone and A-coding on Github to create builds, all i need is Boost: Thread, Filesystem and System library on armv7s architecture.

Error output:

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/shams/Documents/Sources/Hawk.framework/Release-iphonesimulator/libhawk-engine.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (armv7s): /Users/shams/Documents/Sources/Hawk.framework/Release-iphonesimulator/libhawk-engine.ald: warning: 
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/shams/Documents/Sources/Hawk.framework/Release-iphoneos/libhawk-engine.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (armv7s): /Users/shams/Documents/Sources/Hawk.framework/Release-iphoneos/libhawk-engine.ald: warning: ignoring file /Users/shams/Documents/Sources/boost.framework/Release-iphonesimulator/libboost_filesystem.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (armv7s): /Users/shams/Documents/Sources/boost.framework/Release-iphonesimulator/libboost_filesystem.a
ignoring file /Users/shams/Documents/Sources/boost.framework/Release-iphonesimulator/libboost_system.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (armv7s): /Users/shams/Documents/Sources/boost.framework/Release-iphonesimulator/libboost_system.a

ld: warning: 
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/shams/Documents/Sources/boost.framework/Release-iphonesimulator/libboost_thread.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (armv7s): /Users/shams/Documents/Sources/boost.framework/Release-iphonesimulator/libboost_thread.ald: warning: ignoring file /Users/shams/Downloads/boostoniphone-master/build/armv7/libboost_filesystem.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (armv7s): /Users/shams/Downloads/boostoniphone-master/build/armv7/libboost_filesystem.a

ignoring file /Users/shams/Downloads/boostoniphone-master/build/armv7/libboost_system.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (armv7s): /Users/shams/Downloads/boostoniphone-master/build/armv7/libboost_system.a
ld: warning: 

ignoring file /Users/shams/Downloads/boostoniphone-master/build/armv7/libboost_thread.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (armv7s): /Users/shams/Downloads/boostoniphone-master/build/armv7/libboost_thread.a
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7s:
```

Comment: What compiler flags did you use to build for armv7? Try not setting any `-arch` - IIRC, it worked for me.

Comment: error come up saying no architecture found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Solution was to verify the library architecture using Terminal:

```
otool -h libraryFile.a
```

Output:

```
Mach header
      magic cputype cpusubtype  caps    filetype ncmds sizeofcmds      flags
 0xfeedface      12          9  0x00          1     3       1588 0x00002000
```

cputype and cpusubtype are the values to look for:

for armv7:

cpu type: 12    cpusubtype: 9

for armv7s:

cpu type: 12    cpusubtype: 11

Now i was in a situation were it was impossible for me to update architecture as its third party. so i ended up changing my Xcode build project:

- Xcode setting(blue tab)
- project and target architecture:
- valid architecture added only armv7
- cleaned build and run again

Also a alternative solution was to [Hacking an armv7s library](http://www.galloway.me.uk/2012/09/hacking-up-an-armv7s-library/) using this tutorial. didn't work in my case